Formula for calculating cumulative cost with a fixed rate
I'm trying to figure out a formula I can use in Google Sheets for calculating the cumulative cost of a vendor where my monthly bill increases by the same amount each month and costs grow over time (ie database costs where we pay more and more each month for more and more storage).
For example:
Month 1 = $100
Month 2 = Month 1 + $100
Month 3 = Month 2 + $100
etc.

Formula with your data
REDUCE would work for your example. It uses an accumulator whose result is only returned once all the array values have been processed.
=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(3), LAMBDA(a, v, a + v*100))

LAMBDA  REDUCE  SEQUENCE
Equivalent Formula
=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(3, 1, 100, 100), LAMBDA(a, v, a + v))


Related: SCAN

Thank you. Great answer

Put Month 1 and $100 in cells A2:B2.
Put Month 2 and =B2 + 100 in cells A3:B3.
Select cells A3:B3 and copy them down.
See Creating simple formulas.
